# s3 policy for quota

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a s3 policy rule that can only allow a user to upload so many GB of files?  Basically looking to set a quota on the objects a user can upload.

Here is the rule set that I have now:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserBucketListInTheConsole",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::customers"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["${aws:username}","${aws:username}/*","${aws:username}/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserBucketActions",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::customers/${aws:username}","arn:aws:s3:::customers/${aws:username}/","arn:aws:s3:::customers/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I found a policy such as the following, but it does not seem to work.

```
{
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": ["*" ],
     "Effect": "Limit",
     "Resource": "*",
     "Condition": { "NumericLessThanEquals":{"s3:quota-buckettotalsize": "45"}}
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Unfortunately, of all the controls you can place on an S3 user, this is not one of them.

The policy you mentioned looks be for Eucalyptus Object Storage Gateway, which shares a lot in common with the AWS APIs but has some other options available.

> Check these for further reference: 
> https://docs.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus/4.4/iam-guide/access_policy_quota.html
>   https://docs.eucalyptus.com/